# Prevent Docker Toolbox From Overriding resolv.conf

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Iv'e recently started to use Docker Toolbox, but since we use this in offline environment we have our own registry server.

So I followed these steps so I could use the offline registry server and that the `docker-machine` that runs on the VM will recognize the dns name of the server :

1. Added `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` an `--insecured-registry <offline-registry>`
2. Edited the `nameserver`s properties of `/etc/resolv.conf` file

So far so good, I can pull and upload images from the server, but when I restart the VM (`docker-machine restart`) the `resolve.conf` file gets overwritten and I need to connect the VM and change it again.

Iv'e already tried adding `resolve.conf.head` file but it also got deleted when machine was restarted, also tried to search to the `/etc/default/docker` but couldn't find it.

Also I've tried to search to the `dhcpcd` process that's running but that didn't come up with something.

Thanks!